Create a pdf that contains a flowchart with interactive checkboxes
I want to create a PDF document with a flowchart where each node represents a to-do task. The document should be interactive so that the task in each node contains a checkbox that can be ticked/unticked.
For example, I can use the graphviz library in python to create this flowchart:
from graphviz import Digraph

dot = Digraph(comment='Onboarding Flowchart')
dot.node('A', 'Do this ☐')
dot.node('B', 'Then that ☐')
dot.node('C', 'And then finally this ☐')
dot.edges(['AB', 'BC'])
dot.render("onboarding_flowchart", format='png', cleanup=True)

which would generate the following flowchart:

I stumpled upon multiple interesting packages like graphviz, mermaid-py, reportlab or pyLatTex but coulnd't find any good entry point on how I would approach this problem.
EDIT:
I need an automatized way to generate the pdf. In the best case it would be possible to define the whole flowchart using Markdown or a related syntax like the mermaid syntax. The idea is that the PDF can be generated automatically (without manual use of GUI software) using a code script which uses the user-defined file as an input.
